# Recover files from encrypted drive after erasing and reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: encryption, data-recovery

I had ubuntu 21.10 and upgraded to 22.04 sadly this broke a lot of things so I wanted a fresh install. Using the ubuntu installer I erased the drive, installed ubuntu 22.04 on the same hard drive and chose to also encrypt the drive just like last time.

How can I access the files from the previous install? I know the encryption key for both installs.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no way to recover. Encrypted data that has been overwritten, even if only partially, cannot be recovered.

Comment: Did you back up the header, or do you only have the passphrase? Why did you overwrite the disk if you intended to recover anything?

Comment: @Nmath I only have the passphrase. There is only one folder I forgot to backup.

Comment: You can re-install without format, which allows data to survive, it sounds like you formatted thus erasing prior data during the format/install.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to recover anything.

Overwritten data is unrecoverable.  This makes it very unlikely to recover any data when you reinstall the OS overwriting the old installation.  That's true even if there is no encryption.

Encryption adds another layer of complexity. For parts of the disk that might not have been overwritten, LUKS encryption stores all data in an unreadable state. Without both the encryption header and the decryption key, this data cannot be decrypted.

This brings the chance of restoring anything to zero.